# How can I made it more clear that the user can interact with this field to get to settings?

Tags: ux-field

How could it be clearer that users can access settings by clicking on their profile picture in the left navigation bar? People always have trouble finding this space.

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rzqfm.)

[image: png]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On desktop, some websites like [dribbble](https://dribbble.com/) have a hover effect on the profile image with an informative drop-down:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I like the hover UX.

Comment: Hover effects are a hidden affordance; this still requires people to interact with the element in order to figure out what it is there for. Better would be to add an explicit affordance, such as a text label.

Answer (score 5):

Same as with your other icons: **add a label**.

Profile pictures are commonly associated with the ability to edit your profile and/or user settings, and most people will discover this sooner or later. However, this is not always the case. Therefore, adding a label such as **"My Profile"** (since you're using *"My"* for other labels) should be enough.

Comment: Thank you. I may try this - only difficulty is that we may have other functions here unrelated to profile.